# grails spring secuirity ui without mail field on User domain class

Tags: email, grails, spring-security, forgot-password

In my Grails project I'm using the spring security plugins, that are core, ui and acl.
They works well together but I have a problem with forgot password functionality. Infact, when  I try to recover password (/register/forgotPassword path), I have the following exception:

> No such property: email for class: medicalofficemanager.SecUser
>   Possible solutions: all

Is it possible to create automatically the field email for the SecUser domain class, with some  command in console, or do I need to create it manually?

For your information, versions currently used are (installed in proper plugin window in Intellij Idea IDE):

- Grails 2.2.1
- Spring security core: 2.0 RC2
- Spring security acl: 2.0 RC1
- Spring security ui: 1.0 RC1

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the ACL plugin, but pretty sure there's no console command to add an email field.  Just add it manually.